# Back to SurfaceView from other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview, back

Im making game which aim is to kill zombies, and upgrade your weapons.But I have problem, when im trying pause my game and go to shop, i have no problem but when im trying to back to game - Application crash. here is the code:

```
   public GameView(Context context) {
         super(context);
         gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);

         getHolder().addCallback(new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {

                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       boolean retry = true;
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(false);

                       while (retry) {
                              try {
                                    gameLoopThread.join();
                                    retry = false;
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                       }
                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       //createSprites();

                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                       gameLoopThread.start();
                       thread1.start();
                       thread_level.start();
                       wielkosc_czcionki=getWidth()/25;

                }

                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                              int width, int height) {
                }
         });            
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        void pause(){


        if (!is_game) // is not running
        {
                    paused=!paused;
                    is_game=!is_game;
            }
            else{ // is running
                is_game=!is_game;
                paused=!paused;
                startuj_sklep();
                //startuj_sklep();
            }

        }
       Thread thread_level = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
            if(akt_zabit%(int)level_zabit==0){
            level++;    
            level_zabit=level_zabit*1.5;
            resp_time=resp_time-20;
            pause();


            }

            }
        }

      };    


 void startuj_sklep(){

     Context context = getContext(); // from MySurfaceView/Activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, Sklep.class);
     int tab[]={dolary,zycie_gracza_akt,zycie_gracza_def,poj_mag,szybkosc_strzalu, reload_time_def};
     intent.putExtra("dane", tab);
     context.startActivity(intent);

 }
```

So "pause" method is making whole game stopped and then its using "startuj_sklep"(engish: start_shop). "startuj_sklep" method starts new activity.
and its turning new activity, but when it crash.

```
           back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();

            }
        });
```

> 05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272): java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.Thread.checkNotStarted(Thread.java:871)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1025)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at Morisson.zombieapocalypse.GameView$3.surfaceCreated(GameView.java:149)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:571)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.SurfaceView.onWindowVisibilityChanged(SurfaceView.java:232)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.View.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(View.java:7682)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchWindowVisibilityChanged(ViewGroup.java:1071)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1227)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   05-14 15:48:52.031: E/AndroidRuntime(1272):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

The `surfaceCreated()` callback in the anonymous class in `GameView` is attempting to start a thread that is already running, so you're getting

```
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started
```

Add some logging to see when the callbacks are firing and when your thread is starting and stopping.  That will give you a better sense of how your app is interacting with the system.

You may also find [this article](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#activity) of interest.

(I don't know if it's part of the problem, but I strongly recommend against making your `pause()` method act as a toggle.  You should always know whether the call to `pause()` is expected to pause or resume, and writing it as a toggle creates unnecessary ambiguity.  If the game is paused, and you try to pause it a second time, you should ignore the second request or report an error, not try to resume it.)